# jQuery Ajax POST to GET JSON and return value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Ok so I have a `php` file that when a postcode has been `posted` to it it then sends a `get` request to retrieve some `JSON` data.

The `JSON` outputs like this:

```
[{"AddressLine1":"West George Street","AddressLine2":null,"City":"Glasgow","County":"Lanarkshire","HouseName":"1","HouseNumber":"48","Postcode":"G21BP"},{"AddressLine1":"West George Street","AddressLine2":null,"City":"Glasgow","County":"Lanarkshire","HouseName":"3","HouseNumber":"48","Postcode":"G21BP"},{"AddressLine1":"West George Street","AddressLine2":null,"City":"Glasgow","County":"Lanarkshire","HouseName":"2","HouseNumber":"48","Postcode":"G21BP"},{"AddressLine1":"West George Street","AddressLine2":null,"City":"Glasgow","County":"Lanarkshire","HouseName":null,"HouseNumber":"46","Postcode":"G21BP"}]
```

And I'm using `print_r($result);` on the `php` page to display the result

---

**EDIT**

The HTML of my output looks like so:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<pre>[{"AddressLine1":"Garelochhead","AddressLine2":null,"City":"Helensburgh","County":"Argyll And Bute","HouseName":null,"HouseNumber":"","Postcode":"G840EG"},{"AddressLine1":"Garelochhead","AddressLine2":null,"City":"Helensburgh","County":"Argyll And Bute","HouseName":"1","HouseNumber":"Flat 0","Postcode":"G840EG"},{"AddressLine1":"Garelochhead","AddressLine2":null,"City":"Helensburgh","County":"Argyll And Bute","HouseName":"1","HouseNumber":"Flat 1","Postcode":"G840EG"}]
</body>
</html>
```

---

My JS looks like bellow currently:

```js
$('.btnFind').click(function() {
  var dataString;
   $.ajax({     
        url:baseUrl+'/postcode.php',
        type: 'post',
        datatype: "JSON",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
        //test
        }
        }).error (function() {
            alert('error with finding your address');
        }).complete (function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       //var AddressLine1 = data[0].AddressLine1,
    // AddressLine2 = data[0].AddressLine2,
    // City = data[0].City,
     //County = data[0].County,
    // HouseName = data[0].HouseName,
    // HouseNumber = data[0].HouseNumber;
             alert(data[0].AddressLine1);
    
        });     
      });
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AddressLine1' of undefined
```

My guess is print_r isn't suitable but to be honest its been a while since I used JSON so I'm not up to scratch on it to be fair.

Also its printing on a a balnk html page if that makes any difference too.

---

**Console Log as requested**

```
Object
abort
:
(a)
always
:
()
complete
:
()
done
:
()
error
:
()
fail
:
()
getAllResponseHeaders
:
()
getResponseHeader
:
(a)
overrideMimeType
:
(a)
pipe
:
()
progress
:
()
promise
:
(a)
readyState
:
4
responseText
:
""
setRequestHeader
:
(a,b)
state
:
()
status
:
200
statusCode
:
(a)
statusText
:
"OK"
success
:
()
then
:
()
__proto__
:
Object
```

Comment: alert(data[0]['AddressLine1']) try this and return with echo json_encode($data);

Comment: okay so `data` is not defined. can you try `echo json_encode($mydata);` in your php instead of `print_r`

Comment: can you print variable "data", pls.  `console.log(data);`

Comment: If `print_r()` doesn't do it for you, why not try `var_dump()`? Perhaps the `print_r()` isn't causing the error message?

Comment: @IrfanAli That would make zero difference

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: `complete()` is played even if the ajax failed. Use `success` instead. After that, pars the response with JSON.parse()

Comment: Log has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who posted and commented.

I just realised what daft mistake I made. I never serialised the form first.

I had `var dataString;` when I should of had `var dataString = $("form").serialize();`

total idiot I have wasted 4 hours of my day on something so damn stupid.

Thanks again to everyone for looking.

Comment: hahaha! Nice! Glad you sort it out! These things happen so often! Good luck and good coding! ;)

Answer (score 0):

To return from your PHP to your JavaScript with a JSON use this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

**Edit:**

Also, make sure you give access to your PHP script, I use this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');
```

Comment: Also make sure you have Content-Type header set correctly: header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: Would also be nice to see the output of console.log(data);

Comment: @drodil Yes, Will edit to add headersm so we make sure he doesn't get that error either! Thanks!

Comment: So the data from the get on the php file allready comes back as json if that makes a difference im not creating the json on the php file at the time its an api get request

Comment: @DCdaz oh, I though you were creating the JSON ina  PHP file of your own. In this case, try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`, and see what's the output

Comment: If the output is `{}`, means you get nothing and the error is in the call. If you are getting the object, means the error is in the object handling

Comment: This is what I get "".

Comment: I have also added the console log to my question

Comment: @DCdaz This means you are not receiving data. As suggested in other's comments, try using `.success()`. And see if with success you still receive nothing.

Comment: Iam using success

Comment: figured it out posted answer

Answer (score 0):

Before referring to your object, it should be welcomed to the object.
try this

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
alert(data[0].AddressLine1);
```

Comment: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1, so its already parsed

Answer (score 0):

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(data); 

var AddressLine1 = parsed[0].AddressLine1;
```

Comment: Hey! I think would be `parsed[0].AddressLine1` in your example. ;)